# Simple mount will not work (Android Emulator)

Tags: android, linux, shell

I need to remount the `/system` directory read write on the Android emulator I am using, I have root access but still no success. I am running the shell via adb, I have tried the following combinations:

```
mount -o rw,remount /system

mount -o remount,rw /system
```

I am lost, please help.

p.s I am running the emulator through ubuntu although i don't think this should make a difference

Comment: dud you try adb remount ?

Comment: no I have not tried that yet i'll try, the thing that confuses me is i am running another emulator on a windows box and the exact same command worked fine.

Comment: I have resolved it woop... the version of android i am using is earlier than the on i used yesterday so the argument checking is stronger. I resolved it by specifying the device aswell:

Comment: mount -o rw,remount /dev/block/mdblock0 /system